# Android - connect to mssql database by jdbc

Tags: java, android, sql-server, jdbc, connection

I'm trying to connect to live mssql database directly but I got the erro 
"07-26 16:27:25.407: W/System.err(7136): java.sql.SQLException: Charset 0x0404E00000/MS950 is not supported by the JVM."

Here is the sample program I used by just changing the address/name/pw of the database.

https://github.com/alkber/AndroidByExample/tree/master/AndroidMSSQL2008

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to the JVM installed on your server.
It's caused by a limited language-only package (like US/English-only package).
You have to change the JVM to resolve this problem.

Reinstallaing JVM with complete language package should resolve your issue.

Comment: Sorry that I'm new so that I do not completely understand the solution.
Is that I have to request the database owner to reinstall the JVM on the machine? Or I have to restall JVM in my machine?

Comment: Uninstall JVM from your computer. And reinstall the JVM, while selecting a "full-installation" to ensure all language packs are installed.

Comment: I have download the jdk, but when i click install, i cannot select "full-installation", is jvm means jdk?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use jdbc for best coding and performance. Try to webservices.

Comment: any good example for webservices connecting to existing live mssql server database? thanks :)

Comment: This is just simple example http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json

Comment: I usually follow this steps http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php

Comment: What is the different? :) you need  just mssql connection string other steps similliar.

Comment: I tried to use the standard mssql connection string but failed, because some php hosting(I was trying 000webhost.com which is free) does not support mssql connection ( I guess). Do you have any good php hosting which support it?

Comment: Why do you need exactly mssql? I thinked you have an sqlserver but if you dont use mysql. It's free and easy and less issue..

Comment: i have an existing mssql  server database :(

Comment: Chech this out http://www.dimuthu.org/blog/2008/10/04/mssqlmicrosoft-sql-data-services-in-php/

Comment: I think the conn script is fine (sorry that cannot post the whole script here due to the max length limited),

It just shows the error"Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in /home/a1918144/public_html/test4.php on line 8"

Im using the freee hosting "000webhost.com"